# SQL Server 2014 Express performance tweaks

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2014-express

I have a few customers who are running a third party program and they often complain of slowness when the program searches and even freezes at points. The computers are running i7 3.2ghz with 16 GB memory on a 1 terabyte hard drive. The performance of the actual computer is great. I am in no way a SQL Admin, I can navigate through it and write basic queries like inner joins. Are there any settings in SQL Server Express that I can modify to help performance wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using indexes? if you have large data and you are trying to search for something other than the primary key, then you need some kind of indexes. If you can share the query, I may help.

Comment: It isn't my program, it is a third party application so I can only see their tables/stored procedure and basic stuff. guess I'm wondering about memory allocation/paging type of things.

Comment: If you have access to the database and can run queries, then you can check indexes for a specific table ( google it ). Also, you can run a query to check the top slowest transactions, and from there you can decide how to continue. Sorry but as I don't see the tables or the query, it will be hard to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the 64 bit version?  You may want to verify, I would think the 64 bit system would be able to leverage more ram.

To check which version.  SELECT @@VERSION

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299

Comment: It is 64 bit version. I guess I'm wondering about memory allocation/paging